# best practice to dynamically store local images with flutter - hive, folder

Tags: database, image, flutter, storage, flutter-hive

I am downloading class objects that also contain images to the flutter app and store them locally. Simple data such as strings and numbers are stored in a `hive` database.

However, what is the best way to store the images? I found some comments that storing them directly in `hive` is not a good idea and conversion to base64 and Uint8List seem to emphasize this (actually is Uint8List needed or could I directly store base64 to hive - as appears to be possible with Mongo?).

The most obvious choice for me would then to store the images as a file and only keep the path/filename as a reference in hive.

Or are there better ways of doing?

I have looked-up quite a few questions and answers, but they dealt about either about how to store them in sqlite, hive etc. or about temporarily cached images or about static images that come with the app.

Comment: Tag [Hive] is alredy used for Apache Hive: Hive is a database built on top of Hadoop and facilitates easy data summarization, ad-hoc queries, and the analysis of large datasets stored in Hadoop compatible distributed file system.  Please use flutter-hive tag for questions about hive on flutter, this is completely different proiduct

Comment: sorry, one of the required flutter packages is called only "Hive", that is why I used it. Will use flutter-hive from now on